# Solving the same optimization function over multiple dates within a dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, pulp

I have been working on a dataset with ~100,000 rows of daily basketball stats. My project is to compile the top 9 scorers from each day given the same set of constraints. When running the following code on a slimmed down version of the dataset (only on one date), I am able to compile the optimal mix.

Singular date data set

[image]

```
from pulp import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%m/%d/%Y')
players = pd.read_csv("Date.csv", parse_dates=['DATE'], index_col='DATE',date_parser=dateparse)
players["PG"] = (players["POSITION"] == 'PG').astype(float)
players["SG"] = (players["POSITION"] == 'SG').astype(float)
players["SF"] = (players["POSITION"] == 'SF').astype(float)
players["PF"] = (players["POSITION"] == 'PF').astype(float)
players["C"] = (players["POSITION"] == 'C').astype(float)
players["SALARY"] = players["SALARY"].astype(float)

model = LpProblem("problem", LpMaximize)

total_points = {}
cost = {}
PG = {}
SG = {}
SF = {}
PF = {}
C = {}
number_of_players = {}

for i, player in players.iterrows():
    var_name = 'x' + str(i) # Create variable name
    decision_var = pulp.LpVariable(var_name, cat='Binary') # Initialize Variables

    total_points[decision_var] = player["POINTS"] # Create PPG Dictionary
    cost[decision_var] = player["SALARY"] # Create Cost Dictionary
    
    # Create Dictionary for Player Types
    PG[decision_var] = player["PG"]
    SG[decision_var] = player["SG"]
    SF[decision_var] = player["SF"]
    PF[decision_var] = player["PF"]
    C[decision_var] = player["C"]
    number_of_players[decision_var] = 1.0

objective_function = pulp.LpAffineExpression(total_points)
model += objective_function
#Define cost constraint and add it to the model
total_cost = pulp.LpAffineExpression(cost)
model += (total_cost <= 60000)

PG_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(PG)
SG_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(SG)
SF_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(SF)
PF_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(PF)
C_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(C)
total_players = pulp.LpAffineExpression(number_of_players)

model += (PG_constraint <= 2)
model += (SG_constraint <= 2)
model += (SF_constraint <= 2)
model += (PF_constraint <= 2)
model += (C_constraint <= 1)
model += (total_players <= 9)

model.solve()
```

This works and solves the problem when my data set only contains one date. I wish to add all of the dates in scope & have the optimizer run through each date and come up with the optimal mix for **each day.**

I tried to create a loop that would create constraints for each day, however this errored out

```
from datetime import datetime

start_date = "2021-01-25"
stop_date = "2021-01-27"
start = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
stop = datetime.strptime(stop_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
from datetime import timedelta
while start < stop:
    objective_function = pulp.LpAffineExpression(total_points)
    model += objective_function
#Define cost constraint and add it to the model
    total_cost = pulp.LpAffineExpression(cost)
    model += (total_cost <= 60000)
```

Is it possible to assign the same objective & constraints to multiple dates within a singular dataset? The outcome of this would be to have the 9 optimal players for each date in my dataset.

Comment: Include the data as copy-pastable text too.

Comment: just wanted to throw this out there. There is a really handy package someone wrote that works off the dfs optimizing. You could always look at that as a reference too. the link is [pydfs lineup optimizer](https://pydfs-lineup-optimizer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I am aware of that pydfs lineup optimizer, appreciate you pointing me in that direction but I am not aware of being able to optimize across multiple dates on that one? Will have a double check.

Comment: @JohnC, it would just be the same concept as my solution. You'd just filter out by the day, and feed in that filtered dataframe into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create your list of dates, then iterate through those and feed in the filtered dataframe (by date) into your solver:

```
from pulp import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%m/%d/%Y')
players = pd.read_csv("Date.csv", parse_dates=['DATE'], index_col='DATE',date_parser=dateparse)
players["PG"] = (players["POSITION"] == 'PG').astype(float)
players["SG"] = (players["POSITION"] == 'SG').astype(float)
players["SF"] = (players["POSITION"] == 'SF').astype(float)
players["PF"] = (players["POSITION"] == 'PF').astype(float)
players["C"] = (players["POSITION"] == 'C').astype(float)
players["SALARY"] = players["SALARY"].astype(float)


players = players.reset_index()
date_list = list(set(players['DATE'])) #<-- create the list of dates in the dataframe
date_list.sort()  #<-- sort the dates


for var_date in date_list:
    rows = []
    model = LpProblem("problem", LpMaximize)
    filter_players = players[players['DATE'] == var_date].reset_index(drop=True) #<-- filter by date
    total_points = {}
    cost = {}
    PG = {}
    SG = {}
    SF = {}
    PF = {}
    C = {}
    number_of_players = {}
    
    for i, player in filter_players.iterrows():  #<--then run on that filtered dataframe
        var_name = 'x' + str(i) # Create variable name
        decision_var = pulp.LpVariable(var_name, cat='Binary') # Initialize Variables
    
        total_points[decision_var] = player["POINTS"] # Create PPG Dictionary
        cost[decision_var] = player["SALARY"] # Create Cost Dictionary
        
        # Create Dictionary for Player Types
        PG[decision_var] = player["PG"]
        SG[decision_var] = player["SG"]
        SF[decision_var] = player["SF"]
        PF[decision_var] = player["PF"]
        C[decision_var] = player["C"]
        number_of_players[decision_var] = 1.0
    
    objective_function = pulp.LpAffineExpression(total_points)
    model += objective_function
    #Define cost constraint and add it to the model
    total_cost = pulp.LpAffineExpression(cost)
    model += (total_cost <= 60000)
    
    PG_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(PG)
    SG_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(SG)
    SF_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(SF)
    PF_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(PF)
    C_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(C)
    total_players = pulp.LpAffineExpression(number_of_players)
    
    model += (PG_constraint <= 2)
    model += (SG_constraint <= 2)
    model += (SF_constraint <= 2)
    model += (PF_constraint <= 2)
    model += (C_constraint <= 1)
    model += (total_players <= 9)
    
    model.solve()
    
    row = {}
    for v in model.variables():
        if v.varValue:
            idx = int(v.name.replace('x',''))
            player_name = filter_players.iloc[idx]['PLAYER']
            position = filter_players.iloc[idx]['POSITION']
            salary = filter_players.iloc[idx]['SALARY']
            points = filter_players.iloc[idx]['POINTS']
            row = {'DATE':var_date, 'PLAYER':player_name, 'POSITION':position, 'POINTS':points, 'SALARY':salary}
            rows.append(row)
            
    lineup = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    lineup.loc[9,'PLAYER'] = ''
    lineup.loc[9,'POSITION'] = 'Total'
    lineup.loc[9,'POINTS'] = lineup['POINTS'].sum(axis=0)
    lineup.loc[9,'SALARY'] = lineup['SALARY'].sum(axis=0)   

    print ('Lineup for: %s' %var_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))   
    print (lineup.iloc[:,1:])
    print ('\n\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Lineup for: 01/25/2021
                    PLAYER POSITION  POINTS   SALARY
0             Daniel Theis       PF    44.1   4600.0
1           Thaddeus Young       PF    44.3   4200.0
2              Luka Doncic       PG    82.2  10700.0
3             Delon Wright       PG    55.9   5600.0
4  Shai Gilgeous-Alexander       SG    49.8   8200.0
5          Carmelo Anthony       SF    39.7   4100.0
6              Enes Kanter        C    49.9   6500.0
7            Norman Powell       SG    42.2   5600.0
8             LeBron James       SF    73.6   9800.0
9                             Total   481.7  59300.0



Lineup for: 01/26/2021
            PLAYER POSITION  POINTS   SALARY
0     Terance Mann       SG    34.3   3500.0
1     John Collins       PF    43.7   7400.0
2       Trae Young       PG    49.1  10600.0
3      David Nwaba       SG    34.3   5700.0
4   Reggie Jackson       PG    47.4   5000.0
5       RJ Barrett       SF    29.8   7500.0
6    Royce O'Neale       PF    33.2   4500.0
7      Rudy Gobert        C    55.8   8300.0
8  De'Andre Hunter       SF    36.6   5600.0
9                     Total   364.2  58100.0



Lineup for: 01/27/2021
             PLAYER POSITION  POINTS   SALARY
0  Precious Achiuwa       SF    35.7   3500.0
1       Ben Simmons       PG    50.2   8200.0
2   Khris Middleton       SF    48.5   7900.0
3      Bradley Beal       SG    69.8  10300.0
4        Chris Paul       PG    44.5   7400.0
5     James Johnson       PF    34.9   4300.0
6       Rudy Gobert        C    70.5   8000.0
7    Taurean Prince       PF    36.9   4900.0
8       Buddy Hield       SG    50.5   5500.0
9                      Total   441.5  60000.0
```

Comment: Hi Chitown, I had implemented your logic and it seems like it is now just solving for the last day in my dataset & giving me an error of UserWarning: Overwriting previously set objective.
  warnings.warn("Overwriting previously set objective.")

Comment: I'll have to play around with it. I havent worked with that library you're using. But the logic/theory should be making sense. It's quite possible the model needs to be initialized each time. I made 1 adjustment, see if that chamged anything

Comment: I just reloaded your edited code, the actual overwrite objective error went away but it is still only solving for the last date in my dataset.

Comment: can you share the `Date.csv` you're using. I'll test on my machine to see whats up

Comment: It does do each date, you just need to extract that line up to put somewhere. It appears it only does the last date, because it overwrites each iteration, and when you go to view it, you are only seeing that last overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Each day is a different optimization problem, so you should instantiate the LpProblem object for each day that you want to generate an optimal lineup.

You should wrap your code above in a function that handles the optimization of a single lineup. It takes as a parameter a dataframe of player stats, which is day_players in the snippet below.

You should use `pulp.LpVariable.dicts` to create your decision variables. There is no need to loop over the player names to do this.

Note that you don't want the index of your dataframe to be the date. Instead, keep the date column as is and then loop over the unique dates

```
optimals = []
for day in players['DATE'].unique():
    day_players = players.loc[players['DATE'] == day, :]
    optimals.append(optimize_lineup(day_players))
```

The constraints in your code don't seem to correctly encapsulate lineup requirements. Is it your intention, for example, that a valid lineup could include less than 9 players? It seems like all these constraints should be == given the FanDuel lineup requirements of 2 PG, 2 SG, 2 SF, 2 PF, and 1 C. For a correct implementation for FanDuel basketball, take a look at [this recent article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-solve-optimization-problems-with-python-9088bf8d48e5).

I would recommend using [pydfs-lineup-optimizer](https://github.com/DimaKudosh/pydfs-lineup-optimizer). NOTE: I am a contributor to this project but my role is minor and I gain nothing if you use it. It has good documentation and it correctly handles multi-position eligibility, multiple sites, etc. The "multiple dates" problem you refer to above is solved by instantiating a new optimizer object on each day and then appending the lineups to a master list.

Comment: Coincidentally, I had been working on a notebook showing how to [use PuLP to optimize a lineup](https://github.com/sansbacon/lineup-optimization-cookbook). It goes pretty deep into the internals if you are interested. You can download the notebook and run locally or run it in binder with the link on the front page of the repository.